# Оператор LIKE при поиске и безопасность, php, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, безопасность, like

Скажите как правильно организовать поиск с оператором `LIKE`, ищется на сайте по текстовому полю в бд (php,MySql), через - `" ... where pole like '%blabla%' ... "` Как я понимаю это не безопасно, посоветуйте как лучше сделать.
Получается что в оператор `LIKE` можно передать любое значение, так как туда подставляется любые значения из строки поиска на сайте. 
как пример

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE songname LIKE '$searchData%' ");
```

Comment: Если вы используете привязываемые переменные - то как то так: `where pole like concat('%',?,'%')` и спокойно с помощью bind_param привязываете свою переменную к запросу.

Comment: да, все возможные входящие переменные проверяются, но вот строка поиска на сайте может передать любое значение, как с ней поступить? Вырезать все что может представлять опасность?

Comment: Ну так вопрос не в проверках. вы можете вообще ничего не проверять или использовать минимальные проверки, если не будете подставлять переменные непосредственно в текст запроса и будете использовать bind_param или аналогичные функции mysqli/pdo. А про функции mysql_* в php в наше время надо забыть как про страшный сон, новые версии php их более не поддерживают. хотя существует конечно mysql_realescape_string или как то так, но я этого порекомендовать не могу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($searchData);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE songname LIKE '$query%' ");
```

Но это расширение устарело. Лучше использовать PDO или MySQLi, там так же есть методы экранирования строки перед использованием в запросе.

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.quote.php - PDO

http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - MySQLi